# Gulp compile all on startup and keep watching for changes after

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I want to get gulp to compile every change i make to the project. A full compile at the startup, and watch for changes after that.

I did this and can't get them to work together:

Incremental realtime compile:

```
gulp.task('default' ,function() { //can have a callback function
     gulp.parallel('refreshCss', 'htmlToBuild', 'indexHtmlToBuild', 'systemJsToBuild', 'imgToBuild', 'i18nToBuild');
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.files, gulp.parallel('refreshCss')); //when file in styles folder change, trigger runs
  gulp.watch(paths.html.files, gulp.parallel('htmlToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.indexHtml.files, gulp.parallel('indexHtmlToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.systemJs.files, gulp.parallel('systemJsToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.img.files, gulp.parallel('imgToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.i18n.files, gulp.parallel('i18nToBuild'));
  //takes too much time for node modules (remember to copy node modules)
});
```

Full compile at startup (should also stay watching) //Does not work:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('refreshCss', 'htmlToBuild', 'indexHtmlToBuild', 'systemJsToBuild', 'imgToBuild', 'i18nToBuild'),function() { //can have a callback function  
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.files, gulp.parallel('refreshCss')); //when file in styles folder change, trigger runs
  gulp.watch(paths.html.files, gulp.parallel('htmlToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.indexHtml.files, gulp.parallel('indexHtmlToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.systemJs.files, gulp.parallel('systemJsToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.img.files, gulp.parallel('imgToBuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.i18n.files, gulp.parallel('i18nToBuild'));
  //takes too much time for node modules (remember to copy node modules)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is the answer, this compiles everything once and then stays "watching"

```
function realtime() {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.files, gulp.parallel('refreshCss'));
    gulp.watch(paths.html.files, gulp.parallel('htmlToBuild'));
    gulp.watch(paths.indexHtml.files, gulp.parallel('indexHtmlToBuild'));
    gulp.watch(paths.systemJs.files, gulp.parallel('systemJsToBuild'));
    gulp.watch(paths.img.files, gulp.parallel('imgToBuild'));
    gulp.watch(paths.i18n.files, gulp.parallel('i18nToBuild'));
};
// NEW - FULL COMPILE AND "LISTENING" TO CHANGES
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('refreshCss','htmlToBuild','indexHtmlToBuild','systemJsToBuild','imgToBuild','i18nToBuild'), realtime());
```

(Edit) I had a really strange project that i just recieved and didn't know anything about Angular.
I was trying to have the code compiling with every change i made.